# What recommened architectures are there for a CMS?

Tags: model-view-controller, content-management-system

The Framework (maybe a light-weight CMS) in question will need to be able to expanded with modules, and be able to be implemented into common web services such as a blogging platform, a forum, and status-posting site (social networking), or simply just a basic webpage or so.  However, all of this functionality needs to be implemented via modules/plugins.  The front end, and admin backend for that matter, need to be fully customizable (via templates/themes) by the end user.

What architecture, or workflow, is best for a system like this.  The MVC architecture sounds great for a project like this, however, after conducting some research on already developed systems such as Wordpress, Drupal, and PHPBB, I have learned that none of these systems use a MVC architecture and rather one of their own.

Are there any other commonly used architectures for web development, other than MVC?  What does Drupal, wordpress, and the other commong systems use?

Comment: To be fair Wordpress, Drupal, and PHPBB all pre-date the resurgence of popularity the MVC pattern experienced when Rails and Django became popular.

Comment: I believe that MVC is just another trendy word, it can be useful if you know what do you need it for but it is not a solution to every problem.

Comment: Can you provide your own insights for this question? It's been a while since you asked this question and I'm interested to know what are the most important aspects you learned from your own experience with writing a custom CMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at orchard its an open source MVC CMS which has a builtin plugin framework and most of the things mentioned above have already been done. Its also pretty easy to write your own modules. http://orchard.codeplex.com/